# Object[] cannot not be converted to String[] in jsp

Tags: java, string, jsp, arraylist, casting

```
<%
    ArrayList aList=(ArrayList)request.getAttribute("read");
    String[] write =aList.toArray(new String[aList.size()]);
%>
```

in above code, i am getting

> incompatible types: Object[] cannot be converted to String[].

if i cast only i will get the answer what i wish, i [google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=convert%20arraylist%20to%20string%20in%20foreach%20&oq=convert%20arraylist%20to%20string%20in%20foreach%20&aqs=chrome..69i57.17950j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=to%20convert%20arraylist%20to%20array%20in%20java) and got lot of solution, but nothing gave me a solution, help me to find out of this problem. thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: Why are you doing that? What you want to do with the `String[]` that you can't do with list? Why are you still using scriplets and not JSTL?

Comment: @RohitJain Sir i want to print the arrayList value in jsp page sir, i am fresher, this is my task sir, they asked me to do without using JSTL tags sir

Comment: This is strange that someone asked you to use scriplets rather than JSTL. BTW if you just want to display values, then you don't need to convert it to `String[]`.

Comment: @RohitJain sir if i use String[], i had problem, i had mentioned below and explained below to JonSkeet sir, pls see and help me out of this problem sir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the type of `aList` is the [*raw type*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) `ArrayList`. That means all trace of generics is removed from it - even from the generic method `toList`.

It's simple to fix though - just use `ArrayList<?>` instead:

```
ArrayList<?> aList = (ArrayList<?>)request.getAttribute("read");
```

Raw types are a pain in the neck in general, and were really only included for backward compatibility - try to avoid them where possible.

Comment: if i use like above solution, i am getting run time error that "java.lang.ArrayStoreException at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(ArrayList.java:393)"

Comment: @Selva: Well that would suggest that your list contains a non-string. What do you *actually* expect it to contain?

Comment: Sir yes sir it contain non-string value also sir, but i want to print all the arrayList value in jsp page.i am searching for past 4 hours sir, help me out sir

Answer (score 1):

First, since you just want to display the value in your `ArrayList`, you don't really need to convert it to an array. You can iterate over the `ArrayList` too.

Second, even if you're converting it to array, and the list contains non-string values, then why do you think you can store it in a `String[]`? Can you store an `Integer` reference in a `String[]`? No. That is why it is throwing `ArrayStoreException`. You should be using `Object[]` only. But as I said, you don't need it. Just iterate over list. And as in other answer, don't use raw types.

```
<%
    ArrayList<?> list = (ArrayList<?>) request.getAttribute("read");

    for (Object value: list) {
        out.println(value);
    }
%>
```

But, that is bad code. You shouldn't use scriplets in JSPs anymore. I don't know who suggested you to use it rather than JSTL. With JSTL you can use `<c:forEach>` tag to iterate and print the values:

```html
<c:forEach items = "${read}" var = "value">
    <c:out value="${value}" />
</c:forEach>
```